# Change BitLocker Encryption to AES-256 Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows, encryption, aes, bitlocker

I'm trying to force BitLocker to use AES-256 level encryption for the entire operating system drive on Windows 10 Pro. The drive is currently encrypted with BitLocker at AES-128 level encryption. I don't see anything online for how to do this. I've tried changing the [group policy](https://www.howtogeek.com/193649/how-to-make-bitlocker-use-256-bit-aes-encryption-instead-of-128-bit-aes/) settings and decrypting/encrypting to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [first decrypt](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c5273aee-9732-4371-ad1c-3183709fa587/change-encryption-type-from-aes-128-to-256?forum=mdopmbam) the drive than encrypt with AES-256. Unfortunately, this is the only solution.

It is also stated here: [Change BitLocker Drive encryption to XTS-AES 256 during OSD with #ConfigMgr](https://blog.alschneiter.com/2017/05/03/change-bitlocker-drive-encryption-to-xts-aes-256-during-osd-with-configmgr/)

> This can be changed using a GPO or CIs in ConfigMgr but then you have first to decrypt the disk, assign the new policy and encrypt the disk again. This is annoying and not very user & admin friendly